# Changing :after background color when :before is hover

Tags: css

How can I change the :after part when the :before part is on hover?

image explaining is here:
http://www.reshop.co.il/fisha/tab.jpg

Need to change the small triangle when the large square is hover
this two part are separated the square had :before and triangle has :After

I had a stupid mistake 
thanks for helping

Answer (score 3):

Whatever the `:before` portion may be (you haven't shown us any code and that image does nothing to explain your markup), you cannot target just that pseudo-element for the purposes of `:hover`. `:hover` and other pseudo-classes can only apply to entire elements, not their pseudo-elements.

You'll have better luck repurposing the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements as actual elements that are children of your parent element, then using `:hover` and a sibling selector to target them accordingly, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/98hEj):

```
<div class="parent">
  <span class="before">:before</span>
  Content
  <span class="after">:after</span>
</div>
```

```css
.parent > .before:hover ~ .after {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: @Mr. Alien: That shows something different... it's closer to Olly Hodgson's answer than mine.

Comment: You should've included that though :)

Comment: @Mr. Alien: I've been really lazy to create entirely new fiddles these days... I should stop that :) Will update my answer in a few.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want without seeing the code, but this should get you closer:

```
div:hover {
    // These styles affect the div when hovered.
}
div:hover:before {
    // These affect the div's :before when the div is hovered
}
div:hover:after {
    // These affect the div's :after when the div is hovered
}
```

Comment: If I'm reading correctly he only wants the changes to `:after` to apply when `:before` is hovered, not the entire element. That won't be possible.

Comment: thanks for helping, but what I have is two separated parts, one is before the div.: